# CSS3 not working when trigered by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an splash loading with CSS/HTML/JS, but am having some problems.

The problem is when trying to make the splash screen disappear with a transition effect, but the transition effect isn't applying.

I am sure my JavaScript is work properly, as it appends the new class `not-displayed` to the `div` element.

```js
const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');
console.log(splash);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('not-displayed');
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.splash {
  z-index: 100000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffff;
}

//all of these code not working
.splash.not-displayed {
  z-index: 20;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f06c65;
  transition: all 0.5298s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5298s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5298s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5298s ease-out;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadein 1s ease-in forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <h1 class="fade-in">
    hello
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things going on here, a transition and an animation. First I removed a lot of unnecessary CSS code to make things clearer.

Your code is working as expected. When the page loads, the "fadein" animation is triggered by the `fade-in` class. The text "hello" fades in from opacity 0 to opacity 1 over the course of a second, as expected.

Meanwhile, your Javascript triggers on page load and adds the class `not-displayed` to the outer div after two seconds. This triggers the transition effect, which after half a second applies a red background to the div as it fades the div out, bringing it back to opacity 0.

I'm not sure what specifically you are trying to achieve here, but you have wired up a successful transition and animation effect.

```js
const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');
console.log(splash);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('not-displayed');
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.splash.not-displayed {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #f06c65;
  transition: all 0.5298s ease-out;
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadein 1s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="splash">
  <h1 class="fade-in">
    hello
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is when the splash diappear , just disappear without any transition effect. but i try to clean the code as you said. its work propperly thx.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('not-displayed');
  }, 2000);
});
```

you are adding new class to remove the `.splash` and then add new class `not-displayed`

Comment: I don't think that is the case.

Comment: I don't think that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is working just fine, except you have given `opacity: 0` to the `not-displayed` class.

```js
const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');
console.log(splash);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('not-displayed');
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.splash {
  z-index: 100000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffff;
}


.not-displayed {
  z-index: 20;
/*   opacity: 0; */
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f06c65;
  transition: all 0.5298s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5298s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5298s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5298s ease-out;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadein 1s ease-in forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <h1 class="fade-in">
    hello
  </h1>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sirajalam049/pen/bGEqVxE?editors=0110)

Answer (score -1):

You should set the transition to `.splash` not to `.splash.not-displayed`

Comment: Doesn't affect the behaviour.